# unicode characters do not appear in gnome terminal for vim airline

Tags: 14.10, gnome-terminal, vim, unicode, utf-8

I know this has been asked a few times but none of the answers worked for me.

I use the gnome terminal as default in Ubuntu 14.10 and I can't get unicode characters to show properly, mainly in vim airline.

I have set character encoding to unicode UTF8 in the terminal menu.

and LANG returns utf8:

```
echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
```

I have installed a patched font from https://github.com/powerline/fonts/

I have probably also tried other tips found on stackexchange that I now can't remember and I still see the weird characters:

[image: weird characters]

When I installed the same font on OSX with iterm it worked instantly.

I have also tried in other terminals on the same system like guake or using ctrl-alt-f1 and the result is the same. I have tried inside or outside tmux as well.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Which *specific* font do you have?  And what did you do to patch it?

Comment: I have installed lots of those in the fonts repository. They are supposedly patched already. (The same fonts in iterm on mac work)  The one I have chosen in the terminal is "Ubuntu Mono derivative Powerline Regular 11". I have tried various fonts and sizes.

Answer (score 4):

I've uploaded a Unicode test file which you should [download](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9751270/) and then `cat` in your terminal.

E.g.:
`cat ~/Downloads/Unicode-sample.txt` and then use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> in the terminal to verify whether all characters display  correctly.

If you get the same results in your terminal as opening the [original source file](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/unicode-sample.html) in your browser, your font is fine; otherwise, it's a dodgy font: use a different one. (I use "Envy Code R")

**And once the terminal is fine, all applications running in the terminal will be fine as well!**

Comment: thanks @Fabby, I can observe two things: first, the result is the same in the browser and in the terminal. Second, there is a significant amount of characters that are not recognized. If you take for instance "Kanbun", I cannot see any character, only the boxes with numbers inside as in the screenshot in the original question. Does it mean there is a system wide problem?

Comment: Kanbun I don't have neither... Kannada: 2 chars missing. Miscellaneous Technical: a block of 7 chars missing. and then another 10-15 missing until the end...  Same-same???

In the browser I've got everything except Kanbun and a few (<10)

Comment: Kannada in my browser looks like [that](http://i.imgur.com/IflK2L4.png) and in vim like [that](http://i.imgur.com/sKO5D33.png). Miscellaneous Technical in the [browser](http://i.imgur.com/uA8fZDv.png) and in [vim](http://i.imgur.com/NcaNMvW.png)

Comment: what about "Envy Code R"?